# PHP Remove extra spaces between break lines

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a string in PHP, i'm able to remove multiple continuous break lines and multiple spaces, but what i'm still not able is to remove multiple break lines if i have an space in the middle.
For example:

```
Text \r\n \r\n extra text
```

I would like to clean this text as:

```
Text \r\nextra text
```

Could also be too:

```
Text \r\n \r\nextra text
```

Don't need to be an extra espace after the break line.
What i have right now is:

```
function clearHTML($text){
    $text = strip_tags($text);
    $text = str_replace("&nbsp;", " ", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[[:blank:]]+/"," ",$text);
    $text = preg_replace("/([\r\n]{4,}|[\n]{2,}|[\r]{2,})/", "\r\n", $text);
    $text = trim($text);
    return $text;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Instead of replace, try split-then-join combo. But best of all, consider using specific tools (like HTMLPurifier).

Comment: Try `preg_replace('~\h*(\R)\s*~', '$1', $text)`

Comment: I have posted a more detailed and complete answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove extra whitespace between lines, you can use

```php
preg_replace('~\h*(\R)\s*~', '$1', $text)
```

The regex matches:

- `\h*` - 0 or more horizontal whitespaces
- `(\R)` - Group 1: any line ending sequence (the replacement is `$1`, just this group vaue)
- `\s*` - one or more whitespaces

The whitespace shrinking part can be merged to a single `preg_replace` call with the  `(?:&nbsp;|\h)+` regex that matches one or more occurrences of an `&nbsp;` string or a horizontal whitespace.

**NOTE**: If you have Unicode texts, you will need `u` flag.

The whole cleaning function can look like

```php
function clearHTML($text){
    $text = strip_tags($text);
    $text = preg_replace("~(?:&nbsp;|\h)+~u", " ", $text);
    $text = preg_replace('~\h*(\R)\s*~u', '$1', $text);
    return trim($text);
}
```